# socket.io: What's the correct way to install it?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've been able to get `npm` installed but there are a lot of things that don't seem to work.

My first question is what is going on here:

```
steven@steven-VirtualBox:~/Documents/node$ sudo npm install socket.io

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: No such module
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/output.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/log.js:21:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
```

I seem to end up here a lot (line 201).

This command works when I **don't** use `sudo`. But I don't know if it does what it should do.

Is `npm` written in javascript? Is there a way I can set it up manually?

Also, I seem to be getting different results running the `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh` command to install npm depending on what directory I am in. What directory should I be in when I run it? It's rather frustrating that I don't really know what these scripts are doing behind the scenes.

I find tons of tutorials. They all point back to the same instructions. I follow the instructions. They don't work.... Look for more tutorials.....

I got node.js to compile from src perfectly fine. Ran the benchmarks from there too. That should have been the hardest part!

Comment: upgrade node to 0.6.1 and also reinstall npm and see if you have the same problem

Comment: `node -v` gives 0.6.1 for me. Node seems to work. It's just npm that seems to be behaving quite strange. I'm going to start reading the npm install sh script.

Comment: Do you have the latest npm? I know that old npm does not work with 0.6.1 well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really weird.

Registry down ? DNS issue ?

Try to access this url: http://registry.npmjs.org/-/short

You may want to read the excellent faq here : http://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html

Can you install any other package ?

You also need node version > 0.4 to run npm.

Comment: first link downloads a file containing a bunch of values. So I guess that means it works? Starts off like this: `["2kenizer","3scale","500px","7digital-api","a3","aaronblohowiak-plugify-js",`... Thanks for the link to faq. Hopefully it will lead me to a fix.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about just what npm actually does, where it saves files, and so on. But eventually the right js files ended up in the right places and `node` started to stop throwing exceptions. *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an old npm? Deleting the one in usr/bin fixed this problem for me:

$ rm /usr/bin/npm

Comment: yeah this worked for me too.. Conclusion: Never try to install npm in root directory and better install it in the directory you are working.